# Get key and item onPress TouchableOpacity when items are map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onpress

In below code items are rendered properly and working
But When I Press **TouchableOpacity** it returns event.
I Used **JSON.stringify(event.nativeEvent)** but not working

I want to get the **key value** that set on TouchableOpacity and that item Data.

```
export default class MyLanguages extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        languageData: ["English","Hindi","Tamil","Telugu","Gujarati","Marathi","Panjabi"],
      };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.state.languageData.map( (item,index) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity key={index}
                            onPress={ (event)=>{
                                alert(event.nativeEvent)
                            }}>
                            <Text style={MyStyle.appFontStyle2}>{item}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                )}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`item` and `index` are still in the scope of `onPress` callback, so you can refer to them directly:

```
{this.state.languageData.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={index}
      onPress={event => {
        alert(`${index}: ${item}`);
      }}
    >
      <Text style={MyStyle.appFontStyle2}>{item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
)}
```

Comment: It Give  Error **Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: key**

Comment: @BhaumikSurani Sorry, typo - it supposed to be `index`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use curried functions for this:

```
export default class MyLanguages extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        languageData: ["English","Hindi","Tamil","Telugu","Gujarati","Marathi","Panjabi"],
      };
    }

   // Curried function (A function which, when invoked (with an argument), returns another function that depends on the argument
   onPressHandler = key => event => {
      console.log(key, event)
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.state.languageData.map( (item,index) => {

                    // Invoke the curried function with the index as the argument for the key paremeter,
                    // which returns another function which is set as the onPress event handler
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            key={index}
                            onPress = {this.onPressHandler(index)}
                        >
                            <Text style={MyStyle.appFontStyle2}>{item}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                )}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```